# Using MediatR is it possible to create a generic RequestExceptionHandler for any and all requests?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatr

I created a request exception handler with known types as below and the exception is handled.  The only examples I found are doing it this way.

```
using MediatR.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyPortal.Application.Common.Models;
using MyPortal.Application.MyCommands.Commands.CompleteMyCommand;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyPortal.Application.Common.Behaviors
{
    public class RequestGenericExceptionHandler : IRequestExceptionHandler<MyCommand, Result>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyCommand> _logger;

        public RequestGenericExceptionHandler(ILogger<MyCommand> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Handle(MyCommand request,
            Exception exception,
            RequestExceptionHandlerState<Result> state,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var name = typeof(MyCommand).Name;
            _logger.LogError("MyPortal Request Exception {@Request}",
                    name, exception.Message, request);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use something like this it's not handled:

```
    public class RequestGenericExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TRequest> _logger;

        public RequestGenericExceptionHandler(ILogger<TRequest> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Handle(TRequest request,
            Exception exception,
            RequestExceptionHandlerState<TResponse> state,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var name = typeof(TRequest).Name;
            _logger.LogError("MyPortal Request Exception {@Request}",
                    name, exception.Message, request);
        }
    }
```

I'm using .Net Core 3.1, Mediator 8.0.1, and MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyIntjection 8.0.0 and this is my only dependency injection:

```
            services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to make these changes:

```
public class RequestGenericExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException> : IRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>
    where TException : Exception {

    public async Task Handle(TRequest request,
        TException exception,
        RequestExceptionHandlerState<TResponse> state,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {}
}
```

This line is only needed if not using `MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyIntjection`:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>), typeof(RequestGenericExceptionHandler<,,>));
```

Reference: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/486

Comment: This was really, really helpful for me.  There are no good articles online that I could find which explains this concept.  And the code on Github is not complete.

Comment: Here's some **inspiration for the** *exception handling* **implementation code**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74699898/495455

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work. Also if you want to return a generic response for exception you can make all your response class implement same interface and then return a generic one

```
public class GenericRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException> : IRequestExceptionHandler<TRequest, TResponse, TException>
    where TRequest : IRequest
    where TResponse : Result
    where TException : Exception
{
    private readonly ILogger<TRequest> _logger;
    public GenericRequestExceptionHandler(ILogger<TRequest> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }
    public async Task Handle(TRequest request, TException exception, RequestExceptionHandlerState<TResponse> state, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, $"Error occurs on handling {nameof(TRequest)}");
        await Task.Run(() => state.SetHandled((TResponse)Result.Failure(new string[] { exception.Message })));
    }
}
```