# Accessing methods from interface after creating object from Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#

How do I access the interface implementations from an object?

```
interface IGraphicsObject
{
    Draw();
    Delete();
}
```

I create 3 classes: `Square`, `Circle` and `Triangle`, all implementing `IGraphicsObject`. Then I do something like

```
object Shape = Activator.CreateInstance("myShapes", "Square");
```

Then I want to be able to type:

```
Shape.Draw();
Shape.Delete();
```

etc.

How do I do that?

Comment: That is not the way, you must have a factory method that create that type of interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert object returned by Activator.CreateInstance to the type it converted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751108/how-to-convert-object-returned-by-activator-createinstance-to-the-type-it-conver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast to `IGraphicsObject`

```
IGraphicsObject Shape = (IGraphicsObject)Activator.CreateInstance("myShapes", "Square");
```

With the created instance now, you can invoke the interface methods

```
Shape.Draw();
Shape.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to typecast it, but you can do it a bit better by:

```
    public interface IGraphicsObject
    {
        void Draw();
        void Delete();
    }

    public class Square : IGraphicsObject
    {
        public Square(string mysharpes, string square)
        {
        }

        // fill out...
    }

    public class Circle : IGraphicsObject
    {
        public Circle(string mysharpes, string square)
        {
        }

        // fill out...
    }

    public class Triangle : IGraphicsObject
    {
        public Triangle(string mysharpes, string square)
        {
        }

        // fill out...
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public IGraphicsObject CreateInstance<T>(string mysharpes, string square) where T : IGraphicsObject
        {
            return (IGraphicsObject) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), mysharpes, square);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var shape1 = CreateInstance<Square>("mysharpes", "square");
            var shape2 = CreateInstance<Circle>("mysharpes", "square");
            var shape3 = CreateInstance<Triangle>("mysharpes", "square");

            Draw(shape1,shape2,shape3);
        }

        public void Draw( params IGraphicsObject[] shapes )
        {
            foreach( var shape in shapes )
               shape.Draw();
        }
    }
```

So you ensure that only types that implement the interface is allowed for the typecasting creation method.

Comment: Sorry, this got very confusing.  My original post was so that I could create any shape, any number of times and simply call the same method to draw or dispose of it of a canvas.  Not knowing which shape it was until the user clicked it

Comment: yes, that is also what you get from my answer. All 3 shapes returned from the `CreateInstance` can be called with `.Draw()` without knowing anything of the object type.